# Preloading images in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image-preloader

I want to preload these 4 images. I tried this:

```
<img src="img/1.jpg" style="display:none">
<img src="img/1a.jpg" style="display:none">
<img src="img/1b.jpg" style="display:none">
<img src="img/1c.jpg" style="display:none">
```

It didn't work so I tried this instead:

```
new Image().src = "img/1.jpg";
new Image().src = "img/1a.jpg";
new Image().src = "img/1b.jpg";
new Image().src = "img/1c.jpg";
```

The JS method worked with the background but not with these.

Comment: Can describe "preloading" ?

Comment: @guest271314: Presumably, loading when the page does but without initially being displayed, to avoid latency later when they are shown.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Yes . Not certain if "preloading" at `window` , `document` , or other parent `element` `load` event ? , not included at OP ?

Comment: @guest271314: While the exact timing is certainly useful to know, I'm not sure it's crucial.

Comment: What are you planning to do with the images? That my influence the solution. Also what makes you think what you have tries is not working, as from what I can tell, they should.

Answer (score 3):

Try utilizing `$.Deferred()` , `.queue()`

```js
var images = ["http://lorempixel.com/1200/800/cats/"
             , "http://lorempixel.com/1200/800/nature/"
             , "http://lorempixel.com/1200/800/animals/"
             , "http://lorempixel.com/1200/800/technics/"
             ];
    // do stuff when image loaded
    var loadImage = function loadImage(elem) {
      return $(elem).fadeTo(500, "1.0", "linear"); 
    };
    
    // load images
    var loadImages = function loadImages(urls, image, complete) {
        // `this` : `document`
        urls.forEach(function(imageSrc, i) {
          var img = new Image;
          var dfd = new $.Deferred();
          // return `this` : `document`
          dfd.then(function(ready) {
              loadImage(ready);   
              return this
          }, function(error) {
             console.log(error)
          })
          .always(function() {
             console.log(complete, urls.length);
             return urls.length === complete 
                    ? $(this)
                      .data("complete", complete + " images loaded")
                      .dequeue("images") // when all images loaded
                    : this
    
          });
          // log errors
          img.onerror = dfd.reject;
          img.onload = function(e) {
            complete = this.complete ? ++complete : complete;
            dfd.resolveWith(document, [
              image.eq(i).prop("src", this.src)
              ]
            );
    
          };
          img.src = imageSrc
          });
          // return `this` : `document`
          return this
    };
    

    $(window).load(function() {
        // init `loadImages`
        var complete = 0;
        // call `loadImages`,
        // `this` context : `document` 
        loadImages.call(document, images, $(".image"), complete)
    
    });
    
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // notify when all images loaded
        $(this).queue("images", function() {
          console.log($(this).data())
        });               
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<!-- note , `src` attribute not included -->
<img class="image" style="opacity:0.0" alt="1">
<img class="image" style="opacity:0.0" alt="1a">
<img class="image" style="opacity:0.0" alt="1b">
<img class="image" style="opacity:0.0" alt="1c">
```

Answer (score 1):

This never actually appends anything to the DOM, I used an array to keep references of the created images, and pass them to an optional callback

```
var paths =  [
    "img/1.jpg",
    "img/1a.jpg",
    "img/1b.jpg",
    "img/1c.jpg"
];

preloadImages(paths);

function preloadImages(paths, callback) {
    var images = [];
    var loaded = 0;

    paths.forEach(function (path) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = path;
        img.onload = onImagePreloaded;
        images.push(img);
    });


    function onImagePreloaded() {
        loaded++;
        if (loaded === paths.length && callback) {
             callback(images);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the images themselves to `display: none;`, set it on the container.

**CSS:**

```
.preload {
    display: none;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="preload">
    <img src="img/1.jpg">
    <img src="img/1a.jpg">
    <img src="img/1b.jpg">
    <img src="img/1c.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a `link` tag in your `head`:

```html
<head>
  <link rel="preload" href="example.png" as="image">
</head>
```

[MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/rel/preload)