# Preload tag IMG without specifying the name of the images

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, preload

I need a script that loads all images of a web page, and then displays it. I would like the script to **preload all TAG**  and then make a web page visible.

I have alrady tried script like JPreloader or a jQuery plugin, but the I want to write in an array the name of the image.jpg and preload all `img` tags without specifying the name of the images!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29044852/preloading-images-in-html/

Comment: Can include `html` , `js` , `css` at Question ?, create stacksnippets , http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: if your problem is, that your page is jumping around while loading images, you have to specify width and height  for your images. Take in mind, that (im not 100% sure), that hiding your 'body' can be bad for SEO.

Comment: @RavenJe There are 3 answers under your question, each solving presented problem in some way. That woluld be nice if you gave us some feedback, like some comments or accept vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your css

```
body {display: none;}
```

In Script Tag

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $(body).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the poor result is that the people don't understand your topic. By the way. It don't make any sense for me, but you can use this:

```
// CSS
body: opacity: 0;

// jQuery
$(window).load( function() {
   // this will fired, when everything is loaded by the clients browser
   $('body').css('opacity','1')
   // or you can animate it
   $('body').fadeTo(500,1); // 500 for 500ms
} )
```

Comment: the thing is that i dont want write all the times the name of the images, i want that jquery load all tag img before to show the page!

Answer (score 0):

If you like to hide only some parts of the page (it would be nice to show at least *something* to user), you can modify the solution like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="img-container">
    <img src="...">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body:not(.body-ready) .img-container {
    display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
   document.body.setAttribute('class', 'body-ready');
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0LtfmsrL/)