# using ajax + jquery's after() function, now wait for images to load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-after

Hi I am using ajax and json for infinite scrolling and then I create a string of html to add to my webpage and call it with jQuery's after() function.

```
  $('.product-panel:last').after(productHTML);
```

Now I need to wait for all the images from my new productHTML string to load and then call another javascript function I created to do some formatting.

I tried like

```
         $('.product-panel:last').after(productHTML).promise().done(function(){
             doMoreStuff();
         });
```

it doesn't work. Can someone help?  Thanks

EDIT: after following adeneo's code this is my final result and it works flawlessly.

```
    var productLength = $('.product-panel').length-1;
    $('.product-panel:last').after(productHTML);
    var images   = $(".product-panel:gt("+productLength+")").find('img');
    var promises = [];

    images.each(function(idx, img) {
        var def = $.Deferred();

        img.onload  = def.resolve;
        img.onerror = def.reject;

        if ( img.complete ) def.resolve();

        promises.push(def.promise());
    });

    $.when.apply($, promises).done(function() {
       productHeight();
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried .`load()` as opposed to `.after()`?

Comment: If I try to use load()  (not very familiar with) and not after(), how would I tell it where to place my new html string? I'll look into it more now though to see if I can figure it out

Comment: If you can see something that you'd be able to check with `.load()`, then run `.after()` then you could possible do it that way. Good luck, let me know how it goes.

Comment: `load` is a shortcut for `$.get`, which is a shortcut for `$.ajax`, it has nothing in common with `after` which is a DOM insertion method, like `append`, `insertAfter`, `prepend` etc ?

Comment: And still with `load` the result would be the same, it waits for the ajax call to complete, not the inserted images to load.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29044852/preloading-images-in-html/

Comment: i tried load() after after() and it seems to work how i wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not quite that easy, you'll have to find all the inserted images and wait for them to load individually, something like this

```
var images   = $('.product-panel:last').after(productHTML).next().find('img');
var promises = [];

images.each(function(idx, img) {
    var def = $.Deferred();

    img.onload  = def.resolve;
    img.onerror = def.reject;

    if ( img.complete ) def.resolve();

    promises.push(def.promise());
});

$.when.apply($, promises).done(function() {
    // all images loaded
});
```

Comment: `var def = $.Deferred;` without invocation `()` appear to return `undefined is not a function ` at `def.resolve`  https://jsfiddle.net/gmjLpk81/

Comment: i tried but couldn't get it to work. $.Defered was giving me an error

Comment: @guest271314 - it's not just the `$.Deferred` that's the issue with that fiddle, it's the fact that `def.resolve` is a function, note that I have it referenced as a callback function, and `def.done` doesn't exist. But it should have the invocation, so I've added that, thanks.

Comment: @Jay - Made a slight change, try it now.

Comment: Amazing! it works exactly how I wanted now. I had to make some minor changes to the first line

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this is working for me

where I generate my html from the json i put an imageCount variable,
and then have this counter for imagesLoaded so far set to 0. Then $(img).load() function is getting called after each image load and then I just keep checking to see if imageCount and imagesLoaded is the same.

```
    var imagesLoaded = 0;
    $('.product-panel:last').after(productHTML);
    $('img').load( function() {
        imagesLoaded++;
        if(imagesLoaded == imageCount){
            console.log("all images loaded");
            productHeight();
        }
    });
```