# Loading images from file with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to load all the images inside a folder(I have more than 20K), to show them to users(just trying to build a page with images everywhere), on page load, using a JS inside my HTML. But I couldn't manage to load images. There is no error on web console also.

What's wrong with this code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <script>               
        var folder = "images/";

        $.ajax({
            url : folder,
            success: function (data) {
                $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
                    if( val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/) ) { 
                        $("body").append( "<img src='"+ folder + val +"'>" );
                        } 
                    });
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also, other solutions without JS to achieve the same thing appreciated as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps your path is wrong. Try `/images` instead of `images/`.

Comment: What is in `data`? In most webservers, requesting a directory won't give you a JSON-encoded list of its contents

Comment: @JohnDoe I used this answer for JS: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32940532/1079908. I'm not sure what that `data` is

Comment: @Saibot requesting a directory on your webserver might get a different response than on the OP of that question did.

Comment: @JohnDoe Maybe, I would appreciate another solution, if you have.

Comment: @dchacke Nope, it's not about the folder name

Comment: It's already clear you don't have server code supplying the data which you must have. You can't read a server directory from a browser ...for obvious good reasons

Comment: I'm the server. I'm running this HTML on my computer.

Comment: But the html and javascript run in your browser and have no server access to read directories. That has to be done with server side programming language

Comment: OK, whats the solution then?

Comment: What server language does server support?... use that to read directory and point ajax at that endpoint

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu. Maybe you can write an answer explaining the way to do it?

Comment: but you have a server package running to be able to open url on `http://localhost` right? whatever language that server package supports is what you need to use. Or manually create a json file for now

Comment: The simplest solution would be to use `input type="file"` with `multiple` attribute set; at chromium / chrome could use `webkitdirectory` attribute to upload entire folder . Would first make sure folder contains only images. If all images have same file name , ending in a number , could use a loop to request each file name

Comment: @charlietfl I don't understand. Of couse I can open `localhost` url. This html is on my personal computer, and not in a virtual machine, I'm just playing with an HTML file to learn.

Comment: @guest271314 Yeah maybe, but I don't have any clue how to do that, maybe you can write a detailed answer?

Comment: as far as browser is concerned that is a server. WHatever server package you are using to enable localhost is what you need to read directory with and create an end point using a server side programming language. If it's WAMP or XAMP for example it would be php, or maybe you are using node.js to run server in which case use node to read it and create a route for that data

Comment: @Saibot See post. Note, only chromium / chrome support `directory` or `webkitdirectory` attributes; will need to select each image in folder for firefox, ie, etc.; though `multiple` should allow this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prerequisite: Adjust chromium / chrome launcher to add required flag , e.g.; `chromium-browser --allow-file-access-from-files` or `google-chromne --allow-file-access-from-files` ; see [How do I make the Google Chrome flag "--allow-file-access-from-files" permanent?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160245/how-do-i-make-the-google-chrome-flag-allow-file-access-from-files-permanent/)

html, having number of `img` elements equal to image files in folder

```
<!-- note , `src` attribute not included -->
<img class="image" style="opacity:0.0" alt="1">
<img class="image" style="opacity:0.0" alt="1a">
<img class="image" style="opacity:0.0" alt="1b">
<img class="image" style="opacity:0.0" alt="1c">
```

You should then be able to use approach described at [Preloading images in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29044852/preloading-images-in-html/) to iterate an array of image file names to load multiple images in succession.

---

Using `XMLHttpRequest()` with `responseType` set to `Blob` , `URL.createObjectURL` , `new Promise()` constructor , `Promise.all()`

```
var arr = ["file:///home/user/path/to/image/file-1"
          , "file:///home/user/path/to/image/file-2"];

function loadImages(src) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onload = function() {
      $("<img/>", {
        src: URL.createObjectURL(this.response)
      }).on("error", reject)
      .appendTo("body");
      resolve(src + " loaded")
    }
    request.onerror = reject;
    request.open("GET", src);
    request.responseType = "blob";
    request.send(); 
  }) 
}  

Promise.all(arr.map(function(src) {
  return loadImages(src)
}))
.then(function(data) {
   console.log(data)
}, function(err) {
   console.log("error", err)
})
```

---

See also [jquery-ajax-native](https://github.com/acigna/jquery-ajax-native) which allows `Blob` or `ArrayBuffer` to be returned from `jQuery.ajax()`

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'native',
    url: "file:///home/user/path/to/image/file",
    xhrFields: {
      responseType: "blob"
    }
})
.then(function(data) {
  $("<img/>").attr("src", URL.createObjectURL(data))
  .appendTo("body")
})
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But as far as I understand, I need to have a `var arr` array size equals to image number, also equal number of `<img ... ` But I have more than 20K images, and this is not practical. Plus, I'm running the html on my computer for now, but I'm planning to host it as a website, and if users need to tweak their browsers to see my website, that's not practical again too.

Comment: @Saibot The initial premise of original Question was that you were performing these actions locally ? Not on a website that was live on web.  That is why included portion about allowing local access to files using a flag at chromium , chrome to use `$.ajax()`  locally. The `img` elements can be dynamically created instead of written in the `html` document. _"I can write a script to name all the images like 1, 2, 3 etc. that's no problem."_ , _"But I have more than 20K images, and this is not practical."_ Whether 20 images or 20k images should not affect process.

Comment: Maybe I don't get what you explain, I have to study these things for a while. Thanks anyway, upvoting your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `input type="file"` with `multiple` and `webkitdirectory` , attributes set, `accepts` attribute set to `"image/*"` , `.change()`, `for` loop , IIFE to create a closure within `for` loop, `URL.createObjectURL()`

```js
$(":file").change(function(event) {
  var files = this.files;
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    (function(n) {
      var img = new Image;
      img.onload = function() {
        $("body").append(this)
      }
      img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(files[n])
    }(i))
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input type="file" accepts="image/*" multiple webkitdirectory />
```

Comment: Nice answer, thanks. But what I want is to load all images from a folder when the page loads, to show them to users. Your example is to post images from folder. I think you misunderstood me.

Comment: @Saibot Do all images have similar file name ? Even if they do not, you could compile a list of file names and use `$.ajax()` to load each file, in succession, into `document` . At `terminal` you could use `$ cd ~/path/to/folder` , `$ ls` to list all files in folder `/path/to/folder` . Once you have the list of files, you can create an array of file names for use with `$.ajax()`

Comment: I can write a script to name all the images like 1, 2, 3 etc. that's no problem. Can you show an example, assuming I have a filename list?

Comment: Yes, will post another solution

Answer (score 1):

In the code listed above, theres no way you are getting anything in the data that is being returned in ajax as url:"images/" is a folder. You would need to set the url to something that supplies the list of paths of the respective files like a json response:

```
{1:"images/abc.jpg",2:"images/abc.jpg"}
```

OR

```
{imagelinks:["images/abc.jpg","images/abc.jpg"]}
```

Then you can supply these text path to the image sources on page.

Comment: Problem is, it is too impractical if you have 20k images.

Comment: Wait wait, you mean I have to prepare a directory list, and use that list in the function?

Comment: Yes a directory list or something on these lines on server side. You can also refer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994212/is-there-a-way-to-return-a-list-of-all-the-image-file-names-from-a-folder-using

Answer (score 0):

The inclusion of "folder" when you append creates a redundancy in the file paths. Remove that and it works great:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>               
    var folder = "images/";

    $.ajax({
        url : folder,
        success: function (data) {
            $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
                if( val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/) ) { 
                    $("body").append( "<img src='" + val +"'>" );
                    } 
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```