# Loading a video file without input upload

Tags: javascript, html, fileapi

I am incidently using react but the fact remains: when I put up a simple page with an input to upload a local file, if I `console.log` the actual file once it has been selected, here is what I get from the console:

```
File {name: "myfile.mp4", lastModified: 1474084788000, lastModifiedDate: Fri Sep 16 2016 23:59:48 GMT-0400 (EDT), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 27828905…}
lastModified: 1474084788000
lastModifiedDate: Fri Sep 16 2016 23:59:48 GMT-0400 (EDT)
name: "myfile.mp4"
size: 27828905
type: "video/mp4"
webkitRelativePath: ""
__proto__: File
```

And so the file loads in the `video` tags and I can watch it. (The code is below...)

Then, if I want to load the same file but from a hardcoded full path instead, like so: `"file:///path/to/myfile.mp4"`, an error pops up `This video file format is not supported.` and what I get back from the console is the exact same path that I had previously hardcoded.

**My question is how should one load a local file by using a hardcoded path instead of selecting a file from an input element?**
OR
**How to create an objectURL directly from a local path?**

I've already tried to `Blob` the file before passing it on to the `URL.createObjectURL` function but, unless I did it something wrong, it didn't work out.

Render function code:

```
  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <input type="file" ref="input" onChange={this.upload} />

        <video ref="video" type="video/mp4" controls loop autoPlay width="720"></video>  
        <div ref="message"></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Functions:

```
  processs = (file) => {
      let fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      this.refs.video.src = fileURL;
  }

  playFile = (event) => {
    let file = event.target.files[0];
    console.log(file);

    //check if video can be played
    if(this.refs.video.canPlayType(file.type) != ""){
      this.processs(file);
    } else {
      this.refs.message.innerHTML = "This video file format is not supported."
    }

  };
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"load the same file but from a hardcoded full path instead"_? Setting the `<video>` element `src` at `html`?

Comment: In react, instead of passing the file as `const file = event.target.files[0]` from the input element, I just created a `this.state({myfile: "file:///fullpath/to/myfile.mp4"})` in the constructor and refer to it as `const file = this.state.myfile`

Comment: You can use `XMLHttpRequest()` to request local file as `Blob`

Answer (score -1):

> How to create an objectURL directly from a local path?

You can use `XMLHttpRequest` with `responseType` set to `"blob"`. `File` inherits from `Blob`, you can pass returned `Blob` to your existing function which expects `File` object. See also [Loading images from file with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35531195/loading-images-from-file-with-javascript/35532179#35532179)

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.responseType = "blob";
request.open("GET", "file:///path/to/myfile.mp4");
request.onload = () => {
  // do stuff with `request.response` : `Blob`
}
request.send();
```

Comment: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: @JeanmichelCote Which browsers have you tried `javascript` at Answer? Have you read linked Question/Answer?

Comment: Try closing chrome, then launching with `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag set. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/160245/how-do-i-make-the-google-chrome-flag-allow-file-access-from-files-permanent/

Comment: Oh yes, I did that. But It didn't change the result.

Comment: Did you close all open instances of chrome? Or only the tab? Are you trying to load a file from `file:` protocol at an origin other than `file:` protocol?

Comment: I have quit entirely. Loading from file://. Also tried loading "http://localhost:3000/path/from/app/to/myfile.mp4"

Comment: _"I have quit entirely."_ What do you mean?

Comment: `localhost` is not `file:` protocol.

Comment: Tried both. None worked. My code may be bad somewhere else. I may just end up using node's `fs`...

Comment: Is the document which you are trying to load from `file:` protocol at `file:` protocol, or `localhost`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123608/discussion-between-jeanmichel-cote-and-guest271314).

Answer (score -1):

Here is a working  demo

[Load Image or Video without Upload](https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-the-html5-file-api-to-work-with-files-locally-in-the-browser)

Hope it helps